# Which method to use for saving game data and also displaying them in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-play-games

I have a game that is super simple, no animations or that kind of stuff, it is some sort of trivia game. I can, already, save user's max. score locally via sharedpreferences, what I want to do now, is to save  max. scores in some kind of server all users' and display them, maybe, in one screen.

I am not asking here for code, I realize that would be hard without seeing my game's source code.

I need any advice here to which method to use for saving user's 'simlpe' data?

Should I use firebase to save all users' max. scores or using Google Play Games would be a better choice?

By the way, I don't want to interrupt user for email, google sign in or any other that kind of methods. User will only update their username and profile photo (if they choose to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use firebase realtime database or firestore to save user data. You don't have to use authentication if you don't want Google sign in.

Check the following :

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database